# Is there a way to quickly extract the parts from a vector without looping?

Tags: arrays, matlab, vectorization

Consider that I have a vector/array such that it looks as follows:

[image]

each part is a sub array of some size fixed and known size (that can only be accessed through indexing, i.e. its not a tensor nor a higher order array). So for example:

```
x1 = x(1:d);
```

if d is the size of each sub array. The size of each sub array is the same but it might vary depending on the current x we are considering. However, we do know n (the number of sub arrays) and d (the size of all of the sub arrays).

I know there is usually really strange but useful tricks in matlab to do things more optimized. Is there a way to extract those using maybe indexing and and make a matrix where the rows (or columns) are those parts? as in:

```
X = [x_1, ..., x_n]
```

the caveat is that n is a variable and we don't know aprior what it is. We can find what n is, but its not fixed.

I want to minimize the amount of for loops I actually write in matlab to hope its faster...just to add some more context.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to extract a sub array `[x_i,...,x_j]` from `x` where `1<=i<j<=n`?

Comment: @eigenchris so yes, we have sub arrays in the big x and we know each sub array is of the same length. Thus, consider x(1:d), that gets us x1. I will add this to the details.

Comment: So, does `d` vary? I got lost in `"The size of each sub array is the same but it might vary depending on the current x we are considering"`. Add sample input-output data maybe?

Comment: @Divakar given an x, d is fixed. But for a different x, d might be different. Another way of saying this is, x is a vector that has parts x1,...xn, and each part is of a fixed size d. But for different vector x' also composed of parts x'1,...x'n, the size of the parts here might be of size d' instead of d.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I would consider simple [**reshaping**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) to keep the output as a simple double matrix

```
x = (1:15).' %'
d = 3;

out = reshape(x,d,[])
```

and further on just use indexing to access the columns `out(:,idx)`;

There is no need to know **`n`** in advance, as `reshape` is calculating it based on `d` and the number of elements in `x`.

---

```
out =

     1     4     7    10    13
     2     5     8    11    14
     3     6     9    12    15
```

---

If you'd insist on something like cell arrays, use [**accumarray**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) with [**ceil**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ceil.html) to get the subs:

```
out = accumarray( ceil( (1:numel(x))/d ).', x(:), [], @(x) {x})
```

[image]